# What is the main reason for having two or more relations with identical attributes?

Tags: database, attributes

I came across this question in an exam paper and I am not sure what is the best way to answer it. Would it be because the data fields are of mutually exclusive groups or is there a bigger reason behind it?

The previous part of this question gave an example like:

> **Consider a pet database with three relations: Cat, Dog, Rabbit, each with identical attributes such as Name, Species, Lifespan.
> What changes, if any, would we have to make if we wish to merge these relations into one while retaining the same information?**

to which my answer was to have a separate key column such as AnimalID, consisting of the type initial and a sequential integer, such as C001 for cats, D001 for dogs etc. Please correct me if I am wrong.

It seems like a fairly simple question that I should be able to answer, but would greatly appreciate any input on this.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If this is an exam question, you would never embed data inside a field, which you have done by using C001. You would simply put the three tables into an Animal table, which has a foreign ey into an AnimalType table, containing a primary key as a description of "Dog", "Cat" or "Axolotl" - thus giving you extensibility!

Comment: It was careless of me to have overlooked that, thank you for the clarification!